# Domain Move - re-directing javascript file and php variables

Tags: javascript, redirect

I'm moving a website domain and setting up 301 re-directs on a page by page basis, but this is posing two problems:

1) How do I re-direct a javascript file (it's a bookmarklet that users have installed, so will need to re-direct to the new site).

2) Is it possible to re-direct php variables e.g. www.domain.co.uk/view/?PID=68 - would a re-direction on /view/ suffice?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: How are you setting up these redirects?  `.htaccess` or another method?  What does your bookmarklet do?  Does it load a file?  Can you tell your users to update the bookmarklet?

Comment: Yes, sorry in htaccess.  The bookmarklet runs a javascript file which in turn runs a php file...  I was thinking about updating the bookmarklet with a link to download the new version, but was concerned this might not be the best user experience.

Comment: It's not a bad user experience to tell them to update their bookmarklet.  It'd be a worse one if it just suddenly stopped working because the old domain went away.  You don't need to make the message intrusive, just add a simple `*new version available*` link.

Comment: If you're using `mod_rerwrite` to redirect, you can use `QSA` (query string append) to send the query string (`?PID=68`) to the new URL.  `RewriteRule ^oldDomain.com/view/*$ http://newDomain.com/view [R=301,QSA,L]` (or something like that)